# Correct understanding of T.() lambda

Tags: kotlin

I'm having trouble understanding `lambda`.

In particular, things like `T.() -> R` in the `run()` is more confusing.

```
public inline fun <T, R> T.run(block: T.() -> R): R = return block()
```

Questions

```
fun main() {
    test {
        this.replace("3","B")
    }
}

fun test(block: String.(Int) -> Unit) {
    "TEST".block(7)
}
```

In this code, in the `block parameter`, `String.()` means to define `block` as an `extension function of the String class`? So block requires `String value` when calling?

and,

```
fun main() {
    "A".test {
        this.replace("3","B")
    }
}


fun String.test(block: String.(Int) -> Unit) {
    block(7)
}
```

When calling the `block` in this code, why don't we need the `receiver type`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in the `block` parameter, `String.()` means to define `block` as an extension function of the `String` class? So `block` requires `String` value when calling?

Yes. The block is effectively an extension function on the `String` class: within the block, `this` is the relevant `String` instance.

> When calling the `block` in this code, why don't we need the receiver type?

Because there's already an implicit receiver. `test()` is itself an extension function on `String`, so within the body of `test()`, `this` is a String. And so you can call any of the methods of `String` without needing to qualify them with `this.` — including extension methods such as `block`.

---

Consider a simpler case with ‘real’ methods instead of extension methods:

```
class C {
    fun a() {
        // …
    }

    fun b() {
        a() // Implicit receiver
    }
}
```

`a()` is a method of class `C`, and so it needs a instance of `C`. But `b()` doesn't need to specify an instance of `C` when calling `a()`, because it already has its own receiver.

It *could* have been written as `this.a()`, but there's no need, as **`this` is always an implied receiver when you don't specify one**. (Some people seem to like an explicit `this.`, but to me it's just pointless visual noise…)

Although extension methods are implemented a little differently ‘under the covers’, the syntax works in exactly the same way. So the call to `block()` in your second example has an implicit `this.`.

Comment: thank you. In the end, it was possible because both `test()` and `block` are extension functions, right? in summary, as in the example of `real methods`, both `block` and `test()` are `member functions` that are `extensions of the String class`, so you can call the `block` in the `test() body` without the `receiver object(String object)`. Because there is implicit `this` inside the `test()` body. right??

Answer (score 1):

> In particular, things like T.() -> R in the run() is more confusing.

```
public inline fun <T, R> T.run(block: T.() -> R): R = block()
```

Here `T`  and `R` are of a generic type, which could be of any data type `Int`, `String` or a `Class` etc. You get the picture.

`block: T.() -> R`, it's saying that the `block` has to be an `extension` function of type `T`, that could return any type `R` and this `R` could be anything, `Unit`, `String`, `Class` etc.

A `lambda` returns the value of its last expression, so whatever expression is on the last line of your `lambda` it would return it, that is of type `R`.

Now when we use that `run` method on any object, it gives us the same object as the `lambda` receiver (`this`) inside the lambda, because our `lambda` is an extension function of the same type on which we've called this.

```
var a = 1
val b = a.run {
        this + 6
        "incremented"
    }
```

On using `run` method on `a`, our generic `T` type becomes an `Int` and our object `a` is available inside the `lambda` as `this`, because, now it's an extension function of `Int`.

In `lambda` our last expression is `"incremented"` which is a `String` so here our `R` becomes a type of `String`. As the `run` method is returning this `R`, the value of variable `b` becomes `incremented`.

---

> In this code, in the block parameter, `String.()` means to define block
> as an extension function of the String class? So block requires `String`
> value when calling?

If `block` is an `extension` function then you won't need to pass a `String`. When you call it on any `String` it would use that. But if `block` is not an `extension` function then you would've to pass it.

---

```
fun test(block: String.(Int) -> Unit) {
    "TEST".block(7)
}
```

.

```
fun String.test(block: String.(Int) -> Unit) {
    block(7)
}
```

> When calling the block in this code, why don't we need the receiver type?

In latter, the `test` method is an `extension` function of `String`, which is available as `this` in the method body, and all of the functions of the `String` are also available, that you can use with or without `this` on the receiver object. As `block` is also an extension function of `String` it can be accessed directly.

Meanwhile, in the former, there is no receiver object of type `String` is available in the method body, which is why you've to explicitly call it on a `String`.